# What exactly is VFIO and how is it used to write a userspace driver for faster packet processing in a virtualized environment?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, driver, nic

I have read a lot about VFIO but I don't understand the following things?

Is this kernel module specifically written for VM's to access the NIC hardware directly via VNIC? How are vnics implemented in,software?

Comment: I think this breaks the "one question per question" rule, and there doesn't seem to be a specific problem here. Please narrow down your problem. Otherwise, it's very much likely to get closed.